# Python: Get object by id in another process

Tags: python, pointers, multiprocessing

### The problem

I am making a multiprocessing chunk generator, but I can't get an object by its id from a child process. I am on Windows 10.

### The code

```
import _ctypes
import classes as pycraft
import multiprocessing

def start_generaion(window):
    # We don't have to worry about infinite loops, because
    # this is going to be run in another thread, using popen.
    try:
        world = _ctypes.PyObj_FromPtr(window).model
        print(world, flush=True)
        
        while True:
            for i in world._queue:
                world.all_chunks[i].generate()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error in world generation process. \n{e}', flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    world = pycraft.world()
    world = id(world)

    world_gen_process = multiprocessing.Process(target = start_generaion, args = (world,))
    world_gen_process.start()
```

### Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of course, these are two separate processes with different address spaces. You `_ctypes.PyObj_FromPtr(window)` to begin with, but if you are, you really have to understand what's going on. Note, this is *not* multithreaded, this is using multiple processes

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is passing the id of a regular object to another process and it is able to successfully recover the object from the id under Linux:

```py
import _ctypes
import multiprocessing
import sys

def foo(id1, label):
    try:
        print(label, id1)
        v = _ctypes.PyObj_FromPtr(id1)
        print(v)
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    finally:
        print('finally')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = {'a': 1}
    id1 = id(d)
    foo(id1, 'Main process id:')
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(id1, 'Subprocess id:'))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Prints:

```
Main process id: 140443371291200
{'a': 1}
finally
Subprocess id: 140443371291200
{'a': 1}
finally
```

However, when run under Windows, all that is output is:

```
Main process id: 1687385043136
{'a': 1}
finally
Subprocess id: 1687385043136
```

The subprocess abruptly terminates without executing the `except` or `finally` blocks for which I have no explanation.

The problem is that when a new process is created with the *spawn* method, as is the case with Windows, that process inherits nothing from the main process. Instead, a new address space is created and a Python interpreter is launched into that space and rereads the source file executing everything at global scope as its way of initializing memory in preparation for calling the worker function (`foo` in my example). But variables, will not have the same address in the new address space except by the greatest of coincidences.

You did not state what platform you were running under but I strongly suspect that it uses *spawn* to create new processes. **But even under Linux although you are able to recreate the object reference, it is really just a copy of the original object (technically there are copy-on-write semantics involved, but once the reference count is increased for the object, that will result in an actual copy being made).**